# Terminology Regarding Basic Properties of Functions

Tags: functions, terminology, math-history

Is there a cultural difference between saying that a function is 1-to-1 or injective, onto or surjective and a 1-to-1 correspondence or bijective?

Comment: what you mean by cultural difference?

Comment: A Bourbaki follower will say injective.  An elementary school teacher will say one-to-one.  Others may use either.

Comment: The other day a professor refused to say injective, saying something like being native of latin countries allows you to use it, o.w. stick to 1-to-1, but I did not really get it.

Comment: What is o.w.? $\:$

Comment: Sorry o.w.=otherwise